# ¿Como obtener el link de un botón de una página web para hacer una función que haga que se descargue en automatico en c#?

Tags: html, c#, archivo, descarga

bueno estoy realizando un sistema en c# y quiero hacer una función para que me pueda descargar un archivo excel en automático sin yo tener que entrar a la página y descargarlo pero el problema es este, no me sale el link cuando oprimo el botón, esta es la página https://smn.cna.gob.mx/es/estaciones-meteorologicas-automaticas-3
los datos se descargan cuando yo doy click en este botón
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al lado derecho sale la unica información que me arroja pero aparentemente no tiene un link definido, yo se solo lo básico de html, ya intenté buscar el método "downFile()" y ver si asi enviandole un parametro me lo descargara pero no lo encuentro, si alguien pudiera decirme alguna forma para poder hacerlo, u como obtener el link para así ponerlo en mi funcion en c# y ya hacer que pueda descargarse solo.

Gracias de antemano

Pd. pido disculpa por no poder hacer bien la pregunta pero es que no sabía ni como preguntarlo

Comment: Si tienes dudas de cómo preguntar, este es un buen recurso [ask]

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre en este momento es hacer Web scraping. Puedes buscar en Google web scraping in c#. Encnotraras mucha informacion incluso videos. aqui te dejo solo un link para que observes de que se trata https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041115/Webscraping-with-Csharp

Comment: Es posible hacer clicks a botones con web scraping?

Answer (score 2):

No vas a encontrar un link de descarga porque lo que allo define es una funciona jabascript en el `onclick`, vas a tener que navegar la pagina para realizar la accion de descarga.

Esto podrias lograrlo si usas el control `WebBrowser` ya que permite interactuar con el html y realizar acciones en el selector que definas

```
private void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    HtmlElementCollection allElements = webBrowser1.Document.All;
    foreach (HtmlElement element in allElements)
    {
        if (element.GetAttribute("title") == "Exportar a CVS")
        {
            element.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Tambien si te animas se puede hacer con `linq`

```
var element = webBrowser1.Document.All
                .OfType<IHTMLElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault(e=> e.GetAttribute("title") == "Exportar a CVS");
if(element != null)
{
   element.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Por supuesto todo arranca con la navegacion

```
private WebBorwser Web;

private void Form_Load(..)
{
   Web = new WebBorwser();
   Web.DocumentCompleted += Web_DocumentCompleted;

   Web.Navigate("http://...")

}
```

Comment: Con eso que mencionas, es posible hacer clicks a botones?

Comment: claro, solo es cuestion de aplicar bien el selector en el html de la pagina para realizar la accion